# How do I display an Bitmap class object in android without using XML

Tags: android, image

I am trying to display an bitmap I created in and android program, but all the tutorials I find involve either Drawables or XML in order to display them. Can someone show me the steps needed to display an Bitmap in code?

This is not the entirety of the code, this is just the majority, the rest is related to getting the camera working.

```
class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;
private Paint mPaint;
private Drawable bitmap;
private Bitmap currentprev;
private ImageView mImageView;

private Camera.PreviewCallback mPrevCallback = new Camera.PreviewCallback() 
{
        public void onPreviewFrame( byte[] data, Camera Cam ) {
                Log.d("CombineTestActivity", "Preview registered");
                Log.d("CombineTestActivity", "Data length = " 
                        + data.length );
               // currentprev = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray( data, 0, 
               //       data.length );
               currentprev = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(),
                   R.drawable.creature00 );
               if( currentprev == null )
                   Log.d("CombineTestActivity", "currentprev is null" );
               if( mImageView == null )
                   Log.d("CombineTestActivity", "mImageView is null" );
        //Code fails here, gives null pointer exception
                mImageView.setImageBitmap( currentprev );
                Log.d("CombineTestActivity", "Preview Finished" );
        }
};

private OnTouchListener mCorkyListener = new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
                Log.d("CombineTestActivity", "touch registered" );
                mCamera.takePicture( null, null, mPicCallback );
                return false;
        }
};

private Camera.PictureCallback mPicCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken( byte[] data, Camera mCamera ) {

                Log.d("CombineTestActivity", "picture method run" );
        }
};

Preview(Context context) {
    super(context);

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    bitmap = context.getResources().getDrawable(
        R.drawable.creature00);
    if( mImageView == null )
        Log.d("CombineTestActivity", "mImageView is null" );

this.setOnTouchListener( mCorkyListener );

}
```

Comment: Image of a creature that will be used in a game, and in which I will need to edit the individual pixels and merge it with the camera

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `BitmapFactory` to create the `Bitmap` and load it into the `ImageView`.  Like this:

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.my_image);
ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
view.setImageBitmap(image);
```

Comment: Can you show me some basic example code? I'm new to android and not sure what all is needed and how it all goes together

Comment: I have tried making an image view now with a constructor passing in the context, as well as doing it the way you wrote with an XML defined View but each time the ImageView object is coming out as NULL as soon as the initializing statement is finished

Comment: Just updated, for the main.xml I'm just setting the width, height, and ID. and I am baseing all that on how its done in the tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap bm; // some bitmap you have loaded.
ImageView iv; // the image view you want to display the bitmap in

iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Comment: This will not work as `iv.setImageBitmap(bm);` will give you a null pointer exception; you have to do something like `ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);` before doing `iv.setImageBitmap(bm);`